# Updating a field within matching Array in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I recently switched from java mongo driver 3.1 to 3.4 in attempts to use Cosmo db api for mongo on azure. I am having issues with the driver when attempting to modify and field within an array.

My mongo Object looks like so

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af4d4e97bad4700076d7aea"),
    "URI" : "v3egoun@myip"  
    },
    "record" : false,
    "active" : true,
    "audioonly" : true,
    "environment" : "dev",
    "participants" : [
        {
            "user" : "test1.medocity@test.org",
            "state" : "pending",
            "callid" : "null",
            "host" : true
        },
        {
            "user" : "test2.medocity@test.org",
            "state" : "pending",
            "callid" : "74ff79f83c375355058838a1b8d0ec03@test.org",
            "host" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to modify the variables for state and callid within the array for the user matching the query:

```
       BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("URI", URI);
        query.put("participants.user", FROMURI);
        BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject();
       data.put("participants.$.state", newstate.toString());
       data.put("participants.$.callid", XMScallid);


       BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
       command.put("$set", data);
    table.updateOne(query, command);
```

As of now I get the following error.

**Exception in thread "Thread-13" com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Invalid BSON field name 'participants.$.state'**

Anyone have an Idea of how I can modify the state within the participants array for the user provided in the query?

Thanks

Comment: Change all your `put()` to `append()` and do it again. AFIAK `put()` **"overwrites"** values in a `Map` where `append()` adds new ones. The latter is what you want here.  You really should be using `Document` instead of `BasicDBObject` nowadays anyway, but the interfaces are basically the same, and both abstract from `Map`.

Comment: I removed the .$. from the field document and changed the code to `Document query = new Document();
      query.put("URI", URI);
      query.put("participants.user", FROMURI);
     
      Document data = new Document();
      data.append("participants.state", newstate.toString());
      data.append("participants.XMSCallID", XMScallid);
     Document command = new Document();
     command.append("$set", data);
   
      
     table.updateOne(query, command); `   ** While I do not get the error I also don't see any changes in the fields within the array. **

Comment: Because you were already told to use `.append()` instead of `.put()` and yet you ignored that.